# Counting occurrence of data and putting it into a dataset (R Programming)

Tags: r

I am currently analyzing some data from web scrapping a music album ranking website, and I wanted to group years into a range, for example: if the album was released in the year 1992, it would be categorized under the category 1991-2010.

This is the data set right now:
[Data set of music albums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xllcc.png)

The column (Year_Range) is not initially there at first.

```
    year_range1 = c()
    year_range2 = c()
    year_range3 = c()
    year_range4 = c()
    
    for (x in 1950:1970){
      year_range1 <- append(year_range1,x)
    }
    
    for (x in 1971:1990){
      year_range2 <- append(year_range2,x)
    }
    
    for (x in 1991:2010){
      year_range3 <- append(year_range3,x)
    }
    
    for (x in 2011:(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))){
      year_range4 <- append(year_range4,x)
    }
    
    range1=0
    range2=0
    range3=0
    range4=0
    range=c()
    
    for (x in 1:length(year)) {
      if (!is.na(match(year[x],year_range1))) {
        range[x] <- "1950-1970"
      }else if (!is.na(match(year[x],year_range2))) {
        range[x] <- "1971-1990"
      }else if (!is.na(match(year[x],year_range3))) {
        range[x] <- "1991-2010"
      }else if (!is.na(match(year[x],year_range4))) {
        range[x] <- "2011-Present"
      }
    } 

data_set <- data.frame("Sequence" = (1:80),
                       "Album" = album,
                       "Artist" = artist,
                       "Score" = score,
                       "Raters" = rating,
                       "Number of reviewers" = review,
                       "Year_Released" = year,
                       "Year_Range" = range,
                       "Genre" = genre)
```

I used the code above to count the occurrences and then group them up into a separate list, and then entering it into the data set under the Year_Range column. My question is, is there a better way to do this? I feel like this is an unnecessarily long code that can be fixed using 2 or 3 commands. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: i think you are looking for something like this: `data_set$new_column <- ifelse(test = dplyr::between(data_set$Year_Released, 1950, 1970), yes = "1950-1970", no = ifelse(test = dplyr::between(data_set$Year_Released, 1971, 1990),  yes = "1971-1990", no = ifelse(...)...)`. this is not pretty and still requires  some text but still shorter and probably quite a bit faster than your solution

Answer (score 0):

The `%in%` operator should allow you to compute this in a shorter way

```
df$Year_range=NA #create column Year_range, df being your data frame
df$Year_range[df$year %in% 1971:1990] <- "1971-1990"
df$Year_range[df$year %in% 1991:2010] <- "1991-2010"
df$Year_range[df$year > 2011] <- "2011-Present"
```